# WIFI Broadcom BCM43224 not connecting in linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, broadcom

I'm using the STA driver on Linux Mint and since two days ago my notebook can't connect using wifi, it keeps telling me to Authenticate.
I tried to install the b43 driver without success.

Here is the dmesg output:

```
 [2764.479956] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
 [ 2764.484924] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
 [ 2764.484930] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
 [ 2764.484933] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
 [ 2764.484938] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
 [ 2764.484943] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
 [ 2764.484946] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
 [ 2764.484950] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
 [ 2764.484954] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
 [ 2766.784414] ------------[ cut here ]------------
 [ 2766.784468] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 647 at /build/buildd/linux lts-utopic-3.16.0/net/wireless/sme.c:791 cfg80211_roamed+0x89/0x90
 [cfg80211]()
 [ 2766.784472] Modules linked in: rfcomm nvidia(POE) binfmt_misc btusb bluetooth 6lowpan_iphc wl(POE) snd_hda_codec_hdmi uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core v4l2_common videodev media dell_wmi sparse_keymap dell_laptop dcdbas dm_multipath scsi_dh intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm snd_hda_codec_idt snd_hda_codec_generic joydev serio_raw snd_hda_intel snd_hda_controller intel_ips snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep snd_pcm lpc_ich snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq cfg80211 snd_seq_device snd_timer snd mei_me mei soundcore drm shpchp wmi dell_smo8800 mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log hid_generic usbhid hid ums_realtek uas usb_storage psmouse r8169 ahci libahci mii video
 [ 2766.784552] CPU: 0 PID: 647 Comm: wl_event_handle Tainted: P        W  OE 3.16.0-38-generic #52~14.04.1-Ubuntu
 [ 2766.784555] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Vostro 3300/05JR09, BIOS A03 04/26/2010
 [ 2766.784557]  0000000000000009 ffff88013138fdd0 ffffffff8176534f 0000000000000000
 [ 2766.784562]  ffff88013138fe08 ffffffff8106dd9d ffff8800ba81c000 ffff88009a6790c0
 [ 2766.784566]  000000000000009f ffff88009cb1c680 ffff8800baee1a78 ffff88013138fe18
 [ 2766.784571] Call Trace:
 [ 2766.784583]  [<ffffffff8176534f>] dump_stack+0x45/0x56
 [ 2766.784591]  [<ffffffff8106dd9d>] warn_slowpath_common+0x7d/0xa0
 [ 2766.784596]  [<ffffffff8106de7a>] warn_slowpath_null+0x1a/0x20
 [ 2766.784618]  [<ffffffffc0472f49>] cfg80211_roamed+0x89/0x90 [cfg80211]
 [ 2766.784681]  [<ffffffffc085377b>] wl_notify_roaming_status+0xcb/0x150 [wl]
 [ 2766.784738]  [<ffffffffc08523a2>] wl_event_handler+0x62/0x220 [wl]
 [ 2766.784795]  [<ffffffffc0852340>] ? wl_cfg80211_resume+0x440/0x440 [wl]
 [ 2766.784801]  [<ffffffff81091412>] kthread+0xd2/0xf0
 [ 2766.784806]  [<ffffffff81091340>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1c0/0x1c0
 [ 2766.784811]  [<ffffffff8176d998>] ret_from_fork+0x58/0x90
 [ 2766.784816]  [<ffffffff81091340>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1c0/0x1c0
 [ 2766.784819] ---[ end trace 4be1aeeb265daf1e ]---
```

and my driver:

```
 lspci -nn | grep -i network
 12:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4353] (rev 01)
```